# multiprocess.apply_async How do I wrap *args and **kwargs?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyword-argument

I'm trying to get [`multiprocess.apply_async`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) to take in both `*args` and `**kwargs`. The docs indicate that this might be possible with the calling sequence:

```
apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback]]])
```

But I can not figure out how to get the calling syntax correct. With the minimal example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x, *args, **kwargs):
    print x, args, kwargs

args, kw = (), {}

print "# Normal call"
f(0, *args, **kw)

print "# Multicall"
P = Pool()
sol = [P.apply_async(f, (x,), *args, **kw) for x in range(2)]
P.close()
P.join()

for s in sol: s.get()
```

This works as expected giving the output

```
# Normal call
0 () {}
# Multicall
0 () {}
1 () {}
```

When args is not an empty tuple, for example `args = (1,2,3)`, the single call works, but the multiprocessing solution gives:

```
# Normal call
0 (1, 2, 3) {}
# Multicall
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kw.py", line 16, in <module>
    sol = [P.apply_async(f, (x,), *args, **kw) for x in range(2)]
TypeError: apply_async() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)
```

With the kwargs argument I get, for example `kw = {'cat':'dog'}`

```
# Normal call
0 () {'cat': 'dog'}
# Multicall
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kw.py", line 15, in <module>
    sol = [P.apply_async(f, (x,), *args, **kw) for x in range(2)]
TypeError: apply_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cat'
```

How do I properly wrap `multiprocess.apply_async`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't have to use `*` and `**` explicitly. Simply pass the tuple and the dict and let `apply_async` unpack them:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x, *args, **kwargs):
    print x, args, kwargs

args, kw = (1,2,3), {'cat': 'dog'}

print "# Normal call"
f(0, *args, **kw)

print "# Multicall"
P = Pool()
sol = [P.apply_async(f, (x,) + args, kw) for x in range(2)]
P.close()
P.join()

for s in sol: s.get()
```

Output:

```
# Normal call                                                                                        
0 (1, 2, 3) {'cat': 'dog'}
# Multicall
0 (1, 2, 3) {'cat': 'dog'}
1 (1, 2, 3) {'cat': 'dog'}
```

Remember that in python's documentation, if a function accepts `*args` and `**kwargs` its signature explicitly states that:

```
the_function(a,b,c,d, *args, **kwargs)
```

In your case:

```
apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback]]])
```

There are no `*` there, hence `args` is **one** argument, which is unpacked when calling `func` and `kwargs` is **one** argument and processed in the same way. Also note that it's not possible to have other arguments after `**kwargs`:

```
>>> def test(**kwargs, something=True): pass

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def test(**kwargs, something=True): pass
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```